# EFCore Query and selection

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

Hey I am trying to query and find a object that looks something like this:

```
I have already result 
I have id that is quiz id.

So i have both Ids.


var singlequiz = await _context.Quizzes
                .Include(q => q.Questions)
                    .ThenInclude(question => question.Options)
                .Include(qz => qz.Results)
                    .Where(b => b.Id == id)
                .Select(c => c.Results.Select(z => z.Id == result.Id))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

What I am trying to do here is : find an object with id X, then that object with id X has a list of results, I want to get the list, BUT with only the one element that has id of result.Id.

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:
Used this ATM

```
 var singlequiz = await _context.Quizzes
                .Include(x => x.Questions)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Options)
                .Include(x => x.Results)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

            var singleQuizElement = singlequiz.Results.Where(x => x.Id == result.Id).ToList();


            singlequiz.Results = singleQuizElement;
```

Comment: `c.Results.Where(z => z.Id == result.Id)`? Also AFAIK you include statements will not work, cause you have a select statement.

Comment: i think i just got it figured out aswell:             var singlequiz = await _context.Quizzes
                .Include(a => a.Questions)
                    .ThenInclude(b => b.Options)
                .Include(c => c.Results.Where(d => d.Id == result.Id))
                .Where(e => e.Id == id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: But it threw an exception lambda inside include is not valid... :// Oh i didnt know about that select not working with includes, good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var singlequiz = await _context.Quizzes
                .Include(x => x.Questions)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Options)
                .Include(x => x.Results)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=> x.Id == id && x.Results.Any(y => y.Id == result.Id));
```

Comment: `x.Results` is a collection I assume.